# Стихотворные цитаты в прямой речи

Tags: пунктуация, прописная-строчная, прямая-речь

Википедия говорит, что если стихотворения цитата включается в авторский текст как чужая речь и пишется в строку, она заключается в кавычки. Примеров в интернете не нашла. Подскажите, как это оформить в диалоге. Беру в кавычки после тире и сохраняю заглавные буквы даже если всё в одну строку? Например:

– «Жаль только – жить в эту пору прекрасную Уж не придётся – ни мне, ни тебе», – сказал дед.

Answer (score 1):

Корректно: «Жаль только – жить в эту пору прекрасную// Уж не придётся – ни мне, ни тебе», – сказал дед.

Стихотворный текст можно цитировать двумя способами:

> **A.** Соблюдая графический облик строфы, например:
>     "Чудная картина…" А. Фета - зимний пейзаж. Это стихотворение передает ощущения поэта, вызванные созерцанием прекрасной природы:

Чудная картина,

Как ты мне родна:

Белая равнина,

Полная луна…

```
  В этом случае текст приводится без кавычек.
```

Одну-две строки можно цитировать "в строчку", например:
"Чудная картина" А. Фета - зимний пейзаж. **Это стихотворение передает ощущения поэта, вызванные созерцанием прекрасной природы: "Чудная картина, // Как ты мне родна…"**

> В этом случае необходимы кавычки.

*Софья рассказывает о положительных качествах своего избранника:* **"Смотрите, дружбу всех он в доме приобрел:/ При батюшке три года служит,/ Тот часто без толку сердит,/ А он безмолвием его обезоружит…"**

Обратите также внимание, что после прописных букв, соответствующих в стихотворном тексте началу строфу, ставится знак /, одинарный или двойной.

См.: [Gramma.ru Культура письменной речи.](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=5.8)

**О способах введения «чужой» речи в текст (знаки препинания при прямой речи и цитировании)
Николенкова Н. В., Болычева Е. М.**

Answer (score 0):

В приведенном примере нет диалога. А вообще стихотворная речь цитируется в строку или в абзац. При цитировании в абзац кавычки отсутствуют, как и при диалоге, в этом случае выделительная  функция кавычек заменяется выделительной функцией позиции текста.

1) При оформлении стихотворной речи **в строку** используются обычные правила для прямой речи:

Розенталь [XXXII. ЗНАКИ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ ПРИ ЦИТАТАХ](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/53.htm)

Если цитата оформляется как прямая речь, т.е. сопровождается словами автора, приводящего ее, то применяются **соответствующие правила пунктуации** (см. §119–122).
Белинский писал: «Создает человека природа, но развивает и образует его общество». «Двенадцать миллионов людей вне закона!.. Ужас!..» – писал в своем дневнике Герцен, имея в виду крепостных крестьян в тогдашней России.

2) [Выделение кавычками цитат и «чужих» слов](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140#pp140)

**Без кавычек** оформляются стихотворные цитаты, если они приводятся **с сохранением авторской строфы.** Выделительную функцию берет на себя **позиция в тексте**: