# Оформление цитаты из комедии в стихах

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, цитата, поэзия, цитирование

> Молчалин, персонаж комедии А. С. Грибоедова “Горе от ума”, сказал: “Ах!
>   злые языки страшнее пистолета”.

Не будет ли ошибкой использование цитаты из комедии в стихах, как цитаты из обычного произведения?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ошибки не будет. См. [здесь](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=5.8).

> **Б**.  **Одну-две строки** можно цитировать "в строчку", например:
>   *"Чудная картина" А. Фета — зимний пейзаж. Это стихотворение передает ощущения поэта, вызванные созерцанием прекрасной природы: "Чудная картина, // Как ты мне родна…"*
>
> В этом случае необходимы кавычки. [как при обычном цитировании]

Comment: А зачем два слеша в цитате?

Comment: Чтобы показать, где разделяются строки стихотворения в полной строфе.

Comment: При нарушении строфики стихотворного текста для выделения стихотворных строк ставят одинарную или двойную косую черту, либо одинарную или двойную вертикальную линию в том месте, где кончается одна стихотворная строка и начинается другая. Знак препинания перед таким знаком сохраняется, и прописная буква в начале строки после знака — тоже.
 А на 2 строки это правило не распространяется? В интернете ни слова по этому поводу

Comment: «Судьба Родины переживается Блоком как личная судьба, и стихи звучат как страстное признание: "Россия, нищая Россия, / Мне избы серые твои, / Твои мне песни ветровые, — / Как слёзы первые любви!"»
Вот так на ГИА писать точно не стану, т.к. сами проверяющие не поймут.

Comment: @askobar На две строки тоже распространяется. Вот вопрос и ответ на эту тему: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/434601/Стихотворные-цитаты-в-прямой-речи  Если строк много, то пишите в столбик, как у автора стиха. Тогда кавычки не нужны.