# Одинарная или двойная косая черта (слеш) при записи стихотворения в строку

Tags: пунктуация, поэзия, цитирование, оформление-цитат, косая-черта

Где-то на просторах интернета находил такое мнение, что в случае написания стихотворений в строку в конце каждой строки ставится одинарная косая черта (/), а для отделения строф ставится двойная (//). Звучит логично, но существует ли вообще такое правило? Если нет, то как тогда обозначить начало новой строфы? Вот пример оформления:

*Я памятник себе воздвиг нерукотворный, / К нему не зарастет народная тропа, / Вознесся выше он главою непокорной / Александрийского столпа. // Нет, весь я не умру — душа в заветной лире / Мой прах переживет и тленья убежит — / И славен буду я, доколь в подлунном мире / Жив будет хоть один пиит.*

**ДОПОЛНЕНО (12.05.2023)**

"Грамота.ру" не возражает против применения такого принципа (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=310527)).

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> В «Справочнике издателя и автора» А. Э. Мильчина и Л. К. Чельцовой (М., 2014) есть такая рекомендация.
> «В стихотворную цитату, набранную как проза внутри основного текста в подбор с ним, вводят для обозначения стихотворных строк одинарную или двойную косую черту либо одинарную или двойную вертикальную линейку на местах, где кончается одна стихотворная строка и начитается другая.
> Знаки препинания перед таким знаком и прописную букву в начале строки после знака сохраняют» (§ 8.1.11).
> Стихотворный текст, состоящий из двух и более строф, располагать внутри текста в подбор с ним нежелательно: цитату будет трудно воспринимать. Однако, если по каким-то причинам это необходимо сделать, можно использовать предложенный Вами прием. Он логичен и должен быть понятен читателю.

Comment: Мне кажется это интуитивная запись для обозначения пауз, которая интуитивно понятна, даже если не знаешь что это может значить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Строгих правил в этой теме, по-видимому, нет.

Справочник издателя и автора. А. Э. Мильчин, Л. К. Чельцова ([**8.1.11. Дополнение знаками**](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091470.html#id-8%D0%A6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-8111%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)):

> В стихотворную цитату, набранную как проза внутри осн. текста в подбор с ним, вводят для обозначения стихотворных строк одинарную или двойную косую черту либо одинарную или двойную вертикальную линейку на местах, где кончается одна стихотворная строка и начинается другая.

Отвечая на [**Вопрос № 274844**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=274844), Грамота.ру пишет:

> Если стихотворение небольшое (3 строки), то можно привести строки в подбор:
>
> *– А какое ваше любимое стихотворение?
>
> – Вот девушка с газельими глазами Выходит замуж за американца, Зачем Колумб Америку открыл?*
>
> Если стихотворение большое (несколько строф), то такое оформление уже будет неудачным. В этом случае можно оформить как обычное стихотворение (в столбик).

Как видим, здесь между строками вообще нет чёрточек (наверно, посчитали, что заглавных букв и так достаточно, чтобы определить границы), хотя этот портал часто ссылается на вышеупомянутый справочник и считает его авторитетным.
Соглашаясь с ответом "Грамоты", считаю, что не стоит несколько строф писать в подбор (получится нечитабельная "каша"). Неужели только из-за экономии места приходится жертвовать красотой и стройностью стихотворного произведения?

Из одного моего [ответа](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460582/%D0%9E%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%85/460583#460583) (но там ссылка уже не открывается):

> **Одну-две строки** можно цитировать "в строчку", например: <...> *Это стихотворение передает ощущения поэта, вызванные созерцанием прекрасной природы: "Чудная картина, // Как ты мне родна…"*

**Дополнение** (17.03.2023)
В Википедии ([**Косая черта**](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0), заголовок "Служебный типографский знак") есть об удвоении:

> Для указания границ более крупных единиц текста (строф, страниц и под.) косая черта удваивается.

Comment: Лови, Саша, ссылки: (http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=5.8) или (https://www.bgunb.ru/russianlang/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0.html). И... думаю, что описочку-опечаточку *(в стоблик)* можно все-таки исправить.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Первая всё равно у меня не открывается, пишет: "Доступ к странице ограничен, но мы открыли для вас доступ к нашему особенному предложению!" Вторая ок, спасибо! // А! Так это не моя очепятка!

Comment: Ну вот... Красота!