# Слеш как знак препинания

Tags: пунктуация, косая-черта

Когда в тексте используются «/» и «//»? Когда перед этими знаками ставятся другие знаки препинания (запятая, тире и т. д.)?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Косая_черта

Comment: Статья помогла?

Comment: @oleedd, честно, нет.

Comment: Почему? Довольно исчерпыающая статья.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слеш – в прошлом писали *слэш*, но это написание теперь неправильное – используется, когда надо показать, что есть два варианта чего-либо и между этими вариантами можно выбрать (либо оба их применять можно). Ещё он используется иногда вместо союза *и* и *или*. Например:

*Чай **каркаде/каркадэ**.*

*У меня есть 600 **руб./р.**, и я собираюсь купить котёнка на эти деньги.*

***Раздельное/слитное/дефисное** написание наречий.* (Т. е. *Раздельное, слитное и дефисное написание наречий.*)

Если между словами, написанными все в начале предложения посредством слеша, можно поставить союз *и* или *или*, то только первое слово пишется с большой буквы (если остальные слова – это имена нарицательные, конечно). (Смотрите пример сверху.) Ещё пример:

***Зелёные/красные** кленовые листья на продажу.* (То бишь *Зелёные и красные кленовые листья на продажу.*)

Если, однако, мы хотим показать, что можно выбрать написание того или иного слова/фразы в предложении, то пишутся все слова с большой буквы. Например:

***Можно / Могу ли** я это сделать?* (Это пример для иностранцев, как можно спросить разрешение что-то сделать по-русски.)

***Say / Tell me** what happened at the party when you won the quiz.* (Пример из учебника по английскому.)

(В таких случаях слеш намного предпочтительнее и экономнее, чем постановка *и* или *или*, как видно.)

Нужно ли ставить пробел? Ещё чётного правила не было сделано ни Розенталем, ни РАН насчёт этого. Есть, однако, одна умная рекомендация, истекающая из английского языка, которой я следую: если слеш стоит можду одним и одним словом, то мы не ставим пробел (1.); если слеш разделяет не одно и одно слово –  то есть одно и два, два и одно, два и два или более, – то пробел, чтобы не было недопонимания, ставится (2.)

*1. На выращивание **катусов/папоротников** уходят годы; Продажа **носков/трусов**; Есть **чёрно-белые/серо-белые** котята; Есть **чёрно-/серо-белые** котята. **Зелёно-красные/-жёлтые** баклажки.* (Можете увитеть, как слеш ещё можно при дефиснопишущихся словах использовать-таки.)

*2. **Песчаная башня / каменный замок** был в песочнице построен-таки. **Группы людей / стадо баранов** вышло на меня глазеть. **Растение кактус / кактус** требует немного воды, но немало тепла.*

Comment: А когда используется двлйная косая черта? Когда перед одинарным и двойным ставится запятая? Я не раз перед слешем видел запятую.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473496/%d0%9e%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%88-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83

Comment: Если цитируется стихотворение, то запятая перед слешем ставится, если она ставится в самом стихотворении между строками.

Comment: То есть стихотворение можно писать не только в столбик, но и отделять слешем? В принципе, я принимаю Ваш ответ, потому что он мне помог, спасибо.

Comment: Конечно можно! Это давно уже практикуется. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

**Дополнение о пробелах**

Интересное мнение **[у Грамоты](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%88)**, там есть примеры, где обозначены или не обозначены пробелы, причем они касаются **слова:**
*После определения фокусного **сегмента / сегментов** необходимо провести глубокий анализ.*

**Ответ** справочной службы русского языка. Если косая черта соединяет два слова, то пробелы до и после черты **не ставятся**. Но в Вашем предложении косую черту нужно заменить **на союз или**. О функциях косой черты подробно написано в Полном академическом справочнике под ред. В. В. Лопатина.

Но в другом ответе: **продавец/производитель** товара.

Можно предположить, что в первом примере сказывается наличие общего определения: ***фокусного** сегмента / **фокусных** сегментов.*

И еще **интересный момент:** Грамота упоминает союз ***ИЛИ***.  Но этот союз можно отнести к обоим примера, а пишутся они по-разному.