# Сноска к песне: оформление

Tags: оформление-текста

Как правильно?

> 1.1. И зачем с тобою было нам знакомиться? («Голубые гитары», «Ветер северный»).

> 1.2. И зачем с тобою было нам знакомиться? («Голубые гитары»: «Ветер северный»).

> 1.3. И зачем с тобою было нам знакомиться? («Голубые гитары» «Ветер северный»).

> 2.1. Порою жизнь так повернёт — вот-вот померкнет свет (Михаил Боярский, «Поверь в себя»).

> 2.2. Порою жизнь так повернёт — вот-вот померкнет свет (Михаил Боярский: «Поверь в себя»).

> 2.3. Порою жизнь так повернёт — вот-вот померкнет свет (Михаил Боярский «Поверь в себя»).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, здесь действуют те же рекомендации, что и при оформлении цитат.

> **1.** Если указание на автора или на источник цитаты следует непосредственно за текстом, то оно заключается в скобки, причем точка ставится после закрывающей скобки (а не после цитаты)...
>
> **2.** Заглавие произведения, следующее за фамилией автора после цитаты, отделяется точкой и не заключается в кавычки...
>
> **3.** Первое слово указания на источник цитаты пишется со строчной буквы, если не является именем собственным...

• Я бы написала так:
«И зачем с тобою было нам знакомиться...» (И. Гофф. Ветер северный);
«Порою жизнь так повернёт, вот-вот померкнет свет» (Н. Шемятенкова. Поверь в себя);
«Порою жизнь так повернёт, / Вот-вот померкнет свет» (Н. Шемятенкова. Поверь в себя).

•• Эти слова не принадлежат ни ВИА "Голубые гитары", ни Михаилу Боярскому — они только исполнители.
Первое предложение цитируется не полностью, поэтому в конце ставится многоточие (никак не вопросительный знак).
Запись второго предложения можно сделать двумя способами (если хочется показать, что это отрывок из стихотворения, то используется слеш и прописная буква).

••• Вместо кавычек можно предложения оформить с помощью курсива или собственно как цитату (вертикальной полосой). Но ваша нумерация не должна входить в это цитирование (ведь у авторов ее нет).

[Знаки препинания при ссылке на автора или на источник цитаты](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=166#pp166) (Розенталь)
[Одинарная или двойная косая черта (слеш) при записи стихотворения в строку](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473496/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%88-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83) (наш сайт)